# Get MAC address from VLAN1 from server on VLAN2

Tags: routes, mac-address, cisco, arp, vlan

got a networking question for everyone.   Got VOIP phones on VLAN1.  Got a server on VLAN2.  So using a layer 2 switch is it possible to get the MAC address using ARP from a phone on VLAN1 from the server on VLAN2 ?   My research says it needs a layer3 switch.  Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARP is used in L3, which provides the MAC address to IP addresses binding.
Yes, if you have 2 local VLANs that want to talk to each other, you will need a L3 device such as a L3 switch.

From the layer 3 device:

show ip arp | include "IP Address of phone"
show mac address-table | inlcude "MAC Address"

For communication between 2 different VLANs, you will need a L3 device to perform the routing.